# Why does my program stop when it shouldn't, and how do I fix this?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Our geometry teacher gave us an assignment asking us to create an example of when toy use geometry in real life, so I thought it would be cool to make a program that calculates how many gallons of water will be needed to fill a pool of a certain shape, and with certain dimensions.Note, this is in python.

Here is the program so far:

```
import easygui
easygui.msgbox("This program will help determine how many gallons will be needed to fill up a pool based off of the dimensions given.")
pool=easygui.buttonbox("What is the shape of the pool?",
              choices=['square/rectangle','circle'])
if pool=='circle':
    hei=easygui.enterbox("How deep is the pool?")
    radi=easygui.enterbox("What is the distance between the edge of the pool and the center of the pool (radius)?")
    areaC=3.14*(float(radi)**2) * float(hei)
    easygui.msgbox=("You need " + str(areaC) + "gallons of water to fill this pool.")
```

Every time I get to line 8 (areac=3.14...), the program appears to stop, and doesn't display an error, as if the program has finished, but instead it is supposed to display the volume of the pool as seen in line 9. It just won't do it though...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know python, so I could be 100% wrong, but on line 2 you write "easygui.msgbox("
and on line 0 you do "easygui.msgbox=("
Does the equals sign have anything to do with it?

Comment: You were right! It was that stupid equals sign I overlooked! In python, that equal sign assigns easygui.msgbox to a value, so the program actually was supposed to fnish there. Thank you so much, this really helped! I feel pretty stupid now too lol. :)